# Agents freely roaming among attractors in AnyLogic

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic, multi-agent

I am trying to build a multiagent simulation in Anylogic on a GIS map. I have created a Polygonal Node and inserted around 8 attractors. I want a population of agents to freely roam within the polygonal node through the attractors; the agents should be attracted to the attractors but should leave them for another one immediately. How to do this? A step by step solution is appreciated. And once I created the attractors I get an error as in the image. Why is that? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8DtS.png)

I tried creating an agent in the normal process, but I do not know how to let it roam for free.

And I create this model on a GIS map.

Comment: hi there, the error tells us that the space markup shape is not compatible with GIS space. Indeed , for GIS space there is specific one you should try - its called GIS Region. And instead of attractors try use GIS Points. Thats not answering you question completely but i hope it can help you to get a bit further.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.